# intellij , gradle "implementation" doesn't work, transitive dependecies leaks

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

## note:  title updated, the problem seems to be in intellij

I've create a simple repo to test this problem :

https://github.com/fvigotti/gradle-implementation-error

Gradle 5.4.1 but also tested with previous versions before upgrading..

#### Expected Behavior

implementation should not leak "implementation libraries"

#### Current Behavior

everything leaked..

#### Context

I've created an empty ad-hoc sample project to demonstrate this..
https://github.com/fvigotti/gradle-implementation-error

#### Steps to Reproduce

`gradle  clean build  publishToMavenLocal`
then go to another project and import:
`implementation "net.me:library-sample:1.0-SNAPSHOT"`
this should not be exposed :
`import org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder`  but it is!

I'm testing more sources found on github seems that almost everyone uses
`from components.java` without worrying about implementation dependencies leakage... I'm sure I'm missing something here..

thank you,
Francesco

## UPDATE

here is the video of the issue :
https://vimeo.com/334392418

Comment: Seems that I'm not the only one, there are a lot of libraries out there... that leaks "implementation" transitive dependencies.. ie :   
`https://github.com/alkal-io/kalium-kafka/blob/master/build.gradle`

## try to  import the project and you will see all transitive-implementation deps available 
`compile 'io.alkal:kalium-kafka:0.0.1'`

Comment: I don't reproduce your problem, api/implementation separation is working and enabled by default since Gradle 5.0 . I made a fork of your project and simply added a "consumer" subproject:  see https://github.com/mricciuti/gradle-implementation-error   : branch /master is using Gradle 5.4.1 and everything works as expected (no dependency leak) ; branch  /gradle-4.x is using Gradle 4.8 where api/separation was not yet enabled by default => commons-codec library is indeed "leaking" as you observed. make sure you really made your tests with Gradle 5.x (e.g. using the wrapper )

Comment: your example didn't worked for me.. this encouraged me to test further.. and I've found that on console everything works, on intellij the class execute, even if the class cannot be used ( I cannot uncommed that line but run fine.. )   on test package on same class I can also uncomment that line and compile and works.. (from commandline doesnt' work ) I'm investigating what's the problem.. it's weird.. I'll let you know , thank you

Comment: ok I've updated the project https://github.com/fvigotti/gradle-implementation-error  , now in terminal ( linux )  works as expected ( which means that doesn't even compile) , in intellij  it compiles and both classes, test and main run "all fine" °_0 I'm opening an issue on intellij

Comment: are you sure you did configure IntelliJ to use the Gradle wrapper installed in your project ?  maybe it's using you OS installation , which might not be in correct version. ( see menu File->Settings>Build-Execution-Deployment->BuildTools>Gradle :  Use default Gradle wrapper )

Comment: my Os (linux ) gradle is `Gradle 5.4.1` but anyway the problem persist with both wrapper or system gradle, and also tested with jdk8 and 11, same problem.. in intellij I can run the project without errors, and also use `org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder decoder;` in test classes ..  Do you use intelij too ? your experience is different ? I've also opened an issue .. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212120

Comment: yes I use IntelliJ, version 2019.1.1, under Windows.  in IDEA, in the Gradle tool window, I can see that the scope of dependencies is correct in `consumer` sub-project ( commons-csv has 'compile' scope, while commons-codec has 'runtime' and 'test' scopes).

Comment: I was using latest 2018 version of intellij, now I've updated to 2019.1 , I still have the issue.. , I've made  a video to show the problem.. ( no configuration  in intellij-gradle integration work correctly ) all behave the same https://vimeo.com/user98179418/review/334392418/a72bda49c9

Comment: @user218552 The video link in vimeo isn't working.

Comment: Good catch, OP! Do you get the expected behavior in Eclipse? VS Code? @tryman, [*try this*](https://vimeo.com/334392418)

Comment: #NOTE: I've pasted a link which seems to be not public.. the video link is this : https://vimeo.com/334392418

Answer (score 0):

You say in [*your bug report to IntelliJ*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212120#focus=streamItem-27-3475287.0-0), „*I'm surprised no one surfaced this*“. Probably the reason why it hasn't surfaced, is because what you are encountering is not a problem in the real world.

I think the real problem might be a matter of understanding the notoriously arcane nature of class loading in Java.

Class loading must be able to work at both the system level ***and*** the application level. *`Class.forName(String)`* is really working at the system level. But you're sort of driving the system level from the application level with that call on *`Class`*.

Gradle's api/implementation constraints apply at the application level only. Not at the system level. Outside of the context of a Gradle build run, Gradle can't enforce constraints on how the Java class loading system itself is designed to operate.

It's like I shouldn't be able to access my computer's CPU instruction register from a word processor application. But that doesn't mean that the operating system should be forbidden from interfacing with the CPU somehow.

In your case, your *`net.me.consumer.Main`* class is the „*word processor*“. *`org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat`* and *`org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder`* are analogous to instructions in the CPU. And *`java.lang.Class`* is analogous to an operating system.

You can't access the CPU directly from your word processor. However, you can do things in a word processor that cause the OS to interface with the CPU. You're doing something analogous to that with *`Class.forName(decoderClazzName)`*.

The same „*leakage*“ your project demonstrates is repoducable in Eclipse too. And also in Visual Studio Code. In fact, I can add this to both your *`Main`* and *`MainTest`* classes of your consumer project:

```
    org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder decoder = new Decoder() {

        @Override
        public Object decode(Object source) throws DecoderException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Eclipse not only allows it, it automatically creates it for me. Plus it adds the necessary import statements without me even asking it to. And very snappily and happily compiles it with no problems nor complaints. Even though there is no dependency on *`commons-codec`* defined in your consumer's *`build.gradle`*.

And though I haven't tried it in NetBeans, I suspect that you would get the same results in that or any other Java IDE.

The way you've filed a bug with IntelliJ, you would also have to file a bug with every Java IDE, every Java-based application server, every JVM-based compiler, and so on.

I don't think it is reasonable to expect every software vendor out there in the Java ecosystem to comply with the constraints defined by one single dependency management tool. Regardless of how *elephantine* they like to think they are ;)